# How to reduce Noise from OpenGL texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
GLES20.glScissor(0, 0, 100, 100);


GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

GLES10.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);

GLES20.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

GLES20.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

GLES20.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

[image]

all over screen i'm receiving noise on GLSurafece View.
How can i remove it ?

Comment: are you setting texture min and mag filter to linear? (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Filtering)

Comment: also for text, most rendering engine use sub pixel tuning (see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType)

Answer (score 0):

as was mentioned before there are several texture filtering techniques: NEAREST, bi/three LINIAR.
Look at this awesome [tutorial lesson 6](https://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-six-an-introduction-to-texture-filtering/).
[Demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.learnopengles.android) from this tutorial. And of course source code on [github](https://github.com/learnopengles/Learn-OpenGLES-Tutorials/blob/master/android/AndroidOpenGLESLessons/app/src/main/java/com/learnopengles/android/lesson6/LessonSixActivity.java#L181).